# Randomly choosing between two ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two ranges with first names in them, B2:12 and C2:12. I want a formula to first randomly choose between the two ranges, and then randomly choose a result from the selected range.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=INDEX(B2:C12,RANDBETWEEN(1,11),RANDBETWEEN(1,2))
```

Comment: You could of course calculate the last argument RANDBETWEEN(1,2) in a separate cell  first to indicate the choosen group. Say E1 = RANDBETWEEN(1,2), then the choosen candidate =INDEX(B2:C12,RANDBETWEEN(1,11),E1)

Comment: Also, if you want to pick names several times over, have a look at Excel's data table feature. Also see https://superuser.com/questions/1632000/excel-simulating-multiple-recalculations-f9-and-then-pasting-outcome-into-a-t/

Answer (score 1):

You only need to make one random pick:

```
=INDEX(B2:B24,RANDBETWEEN(1,23))
```

will work just fine.

Comment: How would this work if I wanted it to randomize which group gets randomized of the two?